# Resize div with jquery javascript and stretch background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a box div and it has header and body. Contains a div that has a background image.

```js
setInterval(function(){

  var height = $(".box").height();

  $(".box").height(height+2)

}, 1000);
```

```css
.box{    
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #22ff2f;
  width:350px;
}
.box-header{position:inherit; background-color:#9ed;width:100%;}
.box-body{}

.window{
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('http://dailybestlike.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/simple-ideas-products-11.jpg');
  min-height:190px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="window">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

my `.box` is a resizable box, so it will be resize with mouse

But image does not stretch the box. I want to do this with CSS properties. I do not want to set size with javascript. Is this possible?

[WORKİNG DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/806m6803/)

Comment: Can't you simply increase the height of `.box-body`? [Like this.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrp2frq1/)

Comment: You want to stretch image right ? No matter if using javascript ?

Comment: Your `.window` does not scale with the growing `.box`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="window">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS CODE :

```
setInterval(function() {
  var height = $(".window").height();
  $(".window").css({
    'height': height + 100
  });

}, 1000);
```

This code will stretch your image.

Comment: but I change .box size, .box is resizable.

Comment: You want to stretch image or .box ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add height for your `.box-header`, and thanks it you will be can calc your `.box-body` height. Now your `height:100%;` in `.window` will be work properly.

Check this:

```js
setInterval(function(){

        var height = $(".box").height();

        $(".box").height(height+2)

}, 1000);
```

```css
.box{    
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #22ff2f;
        width:350px;
      }
    .box-header{
      position:inherit;
      background-color:#9ed;
      width:100%;
      height: 20px;
    }
    .box-body{
      height: calc(100% - 20px);
}

    .window{
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-image: url('http://dailybestlike.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/simple-ideas-products-11.jpg');
        min-height:190px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box">
      <div class="box-header">
        header
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
          <div class="window">

          </div>
      </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to have a dynamic height of the header, you can dynamically calculate it in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change .box height if you want the background image to resize, change .window height!

https://jsfiddle.net/t87tjmmk/

```
setInterval(function(){

    var height = $(".box").height();

    $(".window").height(height+2); }, 1000);
```

Comment: my .box is a resizable box, so it will be resize with mouse

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what you want here.
[See Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/hotdudehvfun/gnqhurdn/)

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
      header
    </div>
  <div class="box-body">
      <div id='w' class="window">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var w=document.getElementById('w');
    var x=192;

    setInterval(function(){

        var height = $(".box").height();
        $(".box").height(height+2);
    w.style.minHeight=x+"px";
    x+=2;    
    },90);
```

CSS

```
.box{    
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #22ff2f;
        width:350px;
      }
    .box-header{position:inherit; background-color:#9ed;width:100%;}
    .box-body{}

    .window{
        background-position: center;   
        background-image: url('http://dailybestlike.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/simple-ideas-products-11.jpg');
        min-height:190px;
         width:100%;
      height:100%;
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;

    }
```